# Page preview through core service

Tags: 2011-sp1

Please share the classes using which we can do page preview through coreservice in SDL Tridion 2011 sp1 HR2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code so far... In order to preview a page you will need to call the render method with a specific PT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code snippet using coreservice 2011.svc

PublishInstructionData previewInstruction = new PublishInstructionData();

RenderInstructionData renderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData();
renderInstruction.RenderMode = RenderMode.PreviewDynamic;
previewInstruction.RenderInstruction = renderInstruction;

ResolveInstructionData resolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData();
previewInstruction.ResolveInstruction = resolveInstruction;

RenderedItemData dummyPreview = client.RenderItem(item_id, componentTemplateID, previewInstruction, traget.IdRef.ToString());

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the CoreService API. You need this

```
RenderedItemData PreviewItem(
    RepositoryLocalObjectData itemData,
    TemplateData templateData,
    PublishInstructionData publishInstruction,
    string publicationTargetId
)
```

Your page is the itemData, you will need a PT, and a PublishInstructionData

For 2011 you might want to look at this:

```
RenderedItemData RenderItem(
    string itemId,
    string templateId,
    PublishInstructionData publishInstruction,
    string publicationTargetId
)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, for sharing information but this method exists in coreservice 2012.svc and we have coreservice 2011.svc.  Please share class or methods which exists in coreservice2011.svc.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see the updated answer - I have to ask, do you have access to the API docs? A 10 second query revealed this answer

Comment: Yes Chris, I have the API docs; but I was initially looking for method like "Preview" failed to find it in coreservice2011.svc.  After thorough check found this method.  Thanks again.